# pip cannot uninstall scripts

Tags: python, pip, uninstallation

I am using pip to install my code (a bunch of .py scripts) successfully.
I am using the command:

```
pip install --install-option="--prefix=~" -e <folder_name>
```

However, when I try to uninstall the scripts only the .egg file is uninstalled.
My setup.py file looks like this by the way:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='package_name',
      version='1.0',
      entry_points={'console_scripts':['myscript1.py=bin:main', 'myscript2.py=bin:main']}
)
```

How should I make pip be aware of this?

Also I just realized that if I install without the prefix option then pip **is** aware of the installation directory.

Thank you.